# Solving a generic second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ok guys, I have to solve this ODE

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x), \quad 
x>0,\quad y\left(0\right) = 0, \quad 
\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right\lvert_{x=0}=0 
$$
The solution I should get is in the form of 
$$y\left(x\right)=\int_0^x k\left(t\right)\, dt  $$
Moreover, I should tell what the function $\,k\left(t\right)\,$ is in a simple form. I have tried by substitution, with $\,u=y',\,$ but I have to integrate two times $\,f\left(x\right)\,$, and this seems not at all like a simple form... The function $\,k\left(t\right)\,$ is undoubtedly an exponential, but in which form? Hope that somebody can help!

Comment: That very much depends on your $f(x)$.  Note that this is a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, non homogeneous.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a generic function... It is undoubtedly solvable with a substitution method!

Answer (score 2):

The Green's function for $\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is the ramp function $x\theta(x)$, where $\theta(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). We can write the solution for the general inhomogeneous problem as follows. $$\begin{align*}y(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\chi)\theta(x-\chi)f(\chi)d\chi\\&=\int_{-\infty}^x (x-\chi) f(\chi)\, d\chi\end{align*}$$for suitable conditions on $f$.

Comment: Yup, I have already found it in my old notes... I needeed a review! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438613/a-particular-case-of-ode

Answer (score 1):

You are given a form that will do the trick. The thing you need to do now is to differentiate it twice. By comparing result with your equation you will get condition on function $k$ that will make it work. This might involve double integration but you can try to simplify it by changing the order of integrals. This way you can make it a single integral (over slightly modified function)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Use the (Leibniz) [formula for differentiation under the integral with variable limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left( 
\int_{a\left(x\right)}^{b\left(x\right)} f\left(x,t\right)\, dt  \right)
= f\big(x,b\left(x\right)\big) \cdot b'\left(x\right)
- f\big(x,b\left(x\right)\big) \cdot a'\left(x\right)
+ \int_{a\left(x\right)}^{b\left(x\right)} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f\left(x,t\right)\, dt 
$$

---

In your particular case we have
$$
y\left(x\right) = \int_0^x k\left(t\right)\, dt 
\implies
\frac{dy}{dx} = k\left( x\right) \cdot 1 - 0\cdot 0  +  \int_0^x 0\, dt  = k\left( x\right)
\implies
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = k'\left( x\right)
$$
Substituting this back into original equation we get
$$
k'\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right), \qquad k\left(0\right)=0 
$$
After expressing $\,k\left( x\right)\,$ via $\,f\left( x\right)\,$ you can find solution for $\,y\,$ in terms of $\,f.\,$
Hope you can proceed from here.

Comment: When I should use this? When I get the double integral?

Comment: Moreover, the integral is in one variable... Differentiation under integral sign simply gives me back the original function...

Comment: @ale42 Did my edit make the answer more understandable?

Comment: I'm not getting the point...even in this case if I try to integrate I get the double integral of $f(x)$....

Comment: @ale42 I think I misunderstood the essence of your original question, I apologize for that. However, I don't think you can avoid double integration in the solution of your problem for general function $\,f(\leftx\rigjt).\,$ I know you do not consider $\,k = \int f\,$ to be a simple form, but what is exactly a simple form?