# A particular case of ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Guys I'm having troubles understanding this passage on a set of old notes of mine. It illustrates how to solve an ODE like this: $y''=f(t), y(0)=a, y'(0)=b$. Since the associated homogeneous equation is $y''=0$, we notice that the function $y_c=a+bt$ satisfies the homogeneous equation and the initial conditions. Therefore, the particular solution $y_p$ that we should find satisfies $y_p(0)=y'_p(0)=0$. Proceeding with variation of parameters, we let $y_p=A+Bt$, and here $A$ and $B$ are functions of $t$. Then

$$y'_p=B+A'+B't$$

Putting $A'+B't=0$, then

$$y''_p=B'=f(t)$$
$$A' = -tf(t)$$

Integrating we find

$$y_p=\int_0^t(t-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau$$

Since It's easy to check that $y_p(0) = y'_p(0) = 0$, the general solution is

$$y_p=a+bt\int_0^t(t-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau$$.

The problem is that I don't get why inside the integral there's the term $(t-\tau)$. I know that without it things wouldn't have worked out, but from where it comes?

Comment: I would rather work with $y_p=c(x)\cdot(a+bt)$.

Comment: Nope. The solution above works greatly, and is also beautiful. I just wanted to get some additional insight.

Comment: I know it works, but you are assuming two diffrent functions $A$ and $B$, while both of them depend on $c(x)$. So, you could spare yourself an additional differential equation to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, one knows from partial integration that 
\begin{align}
y(x)&=y(0)+\int_0^xy'(t)\,dt\\
&=y(0)-\int_0^x(-1)·y'(t)\,dt\\
&=y(0)-[(x-t)·y'(t)]_{t=0}^x+\int_0^x(x-t)·y''(t)\,dt\\
&=y(0)+x·y'(0)+\int_0^x(x-t)·y''(t)\,dt
\end{align}
which is the Taylor or MacLaurin formula of degree 1 with integral remainder term.